# 1999 GMC Sonoma 2.2L, 5spd, SLS - no reverse lights, suspect transmission

Tags: electrical

No reverse lights. Complete diagnostics reveal; good Fuses, good blubs, good continuity, good reverse light switch. The switch was checked two ways: 1. jumped out with a piece of wire between connection contacts (lights work) 2. remove switch from transmission and physically depress actuator (lights work).

Suspect some slight changes to Transmission (shifts fine) recently; replaced UJoints in drive shaft, replaced center mount bearing, topped off manual transmission fluid. This beauty has 202K "cared for" mileage.

Therefore, I sense that the switch must now travel slightly further into the transmission to facilitate actuation. Am I right?

LOUIS

Comment: just a thought--might the switch be damaged/worn such that, even though it works electrically, it is not being depressed far enough by the trans to complete the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

I would try a replacement switch if available cheaply/easily. I find it hard to believe the transmission wore out the mechanism to depress the reverse switch, and more likely that the switch is faulty in some fashion.

But otherwise the indication is the physical connection of the switch to the reverse mechanism in the transmission.